# HIS ATI HD 5870 iCooler 5 shuts down complete system

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have a new graphic cardd, it's a HIS ATI based  HD 5870 iCooler 5. When I play a game, after 20 minutes, the complete system shutsdown (it's not really shuttig down, but the computer goes off like a crash). The minimal requirements are  a PSU of 500 watt, I use a 430 watt PSU. Can this be the reason?

Edit: When I tried FurMark, the system shuts down immediatly, Could it also be a problem with my CPU core temp?

Update: The problem was indeed the voltage, I replaced the PSU with a stronger one, with more amps on the 12 volt connectors. Now I don't have any problems anymore.

Comment: @Gnoupi: I think it preferable to update that the poster stays within his post. Things are clearer this way.

Comment: Apparently a really high upsurge in electrical usage only happened after 20 minutes of game. The PSU was close enough to your needs, except for demands at the very limit of the video card capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the voltage, I replaced the PSU with a stronger one, with more amps on the 12 volt connectors. Now I don't have any problems anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's a PSU problem, because you manage to get 20 minutes of heavy usage out of your setup.

I would rather go for the video card heating up too much.

You may use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to check on the temperature of the video card:

[image]

Comment: CCC has it's own temp interface, idl the card is 53.0 C, but when I play a game, I can't see the temps, is it possible to log to that file even when the system system shuts down?

Comment: And why couldn't it be the PSU? The watts are to low

Comment: @Chris: My logic says it's not the PSU, but I can of course be wrong. Try to Alt-Tab out of the game to see the temp (may be easier when the game is suspended with a dialog, such as for game options). Or try to put the game into Windowed mode, rather than full-screen, if possible.

Comment: please read my edit too.

Comment: @Chris: SpeedFan is very good at displaying temp (if sensors available) - http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: thank you all for thinking with me, I have updated my post.